# Pegar informações de um arquivo JSON com espaços

Tags: javascript, json

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando JavaScript e nela preciso pegar algumas informações de um arquivo JSON, porém esse arquivo vem com espaços. Gostaria de saber se é possível pegar essas informações mesmo com os espaços?

```
{
     "Meta Data": {
            "1. Information": "Intraday Prices and Volumes for Digital Currency",
            "2. Digital Currency Code": "BTC",
            "3. Digital Currency Name": "Bitcoin",
            "4. Market Code": "EUR",
            "5. Market Name": "Euro",
            "6. Interval": "5min",
            "7. Last Refreshed": "2018-07-27 00:25:00",
            "8. Time Zone": "UTC"
}, ...
```

Comment: Os espaços são as identacões? Se sim, a resposta é sim, quando fazer `JSON.parse` o resultado será o mesmo independente de quantos espaços tenha

Comment: Está tendo algum problema? O normal é pegar os espaços em branco.

Comment: Creio que os espaços não são as identações, utilizando a função parse, eu gostaria de pegar as informações de "Meta Data", mas não consigo pegar essa informação com espaços

Comment: Imagino que é como se fosse o caso: {"name user": "user1"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tive o mesmo problema, tinha que consumir uma API que possuia umas propriedades com espaços e hifens, use:

```
obj["prop 1"];
obj["prop-2"];
obj["prop. 3"];
//...
```